# iPad websites with "-webkit-overflow-"scrolling:touch;" the scrolling just stops working sometimes…

Tags: ipad, css, safari, scroll

This is only for Safari on the ipad

I have the following css on a div with content inside overflowing:

```
#some_div{ 
position: absolute; top:0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; bottom: 0px; 
overflow-y:scroll;
overflow-x:scroll;
-webkit-overflow-scrolling: touch;
}
```

However after a while, or sometimes when hiding and bowing the div, the scrolling just stops working.

Has anyone has this before or knows how to fix it?

Cheers!

Comment: Can you add your website to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Please also mention what iOS version you are using (each version has different webkit revisions).

Comment: Please explain the problem in more detail. The only thing I've seen (on iOS 6) is that when a non-fixed element is scrolled (which gives it focus) and then the fixed element receives a scroll event, it will scroll the entire page. Touching the fixed element (to resume focus) fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get around this "bug" by preventing the default behavior on the body tag

```
$('body').on('touchmove', function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
});
```

I had the problem on an iframe though